Harmonic function related question.
Let $h$ be harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Suppose $h\left(e^{i \theta}\right)=e^{-\sin \theta} \cos (\cos \theta)$ for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Find the value of $h(1 / 2)$. Justify your answer.
Hint: Find an analytic function whose real part agrees with $h$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$.
I already find that $h(z)=Re(e^{iz})$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ by hint. Can I just plug in 1/2 into the expression of $h(z)$?
I feel I missed something.

If two harmonic functions agree on $\partial \mathbb D$ then they are equal inside $\mathbb D$. Hence, the function $h$ you have obtained has to be the right one, so you can plug in $z=\frac 1  2$ to get $h(1/2)$.

Thanks for filling the gap for me. The uniqueness theorem of harmonic function can be proved by the maximal principle of harmonic function. I think I have trouble proving the maximal principle of harmonic function by using the maximum modulus principle(Theorem).
